# If $a,b,c \in \mathbb N$ and $\gcd(a^2-1,b^2-1,c^2-1)=1$, prove that $\gcd(ab+c,bc+a,ca+b)=\gcd(a,b,c)$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

The whole problem is in the title. I'm out of ideas and can't think of a way to solve this, so I'd like to get some help. Thanks.

Comment: One observation : $$a(bc+a)-b(ca+b)=a^2-b^2=a^2-1-(b^2-1)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $r=ab+c,\ s=bc+a,\ t=ca+b.$ That $\gcd(a,b,c)|\gcd(r,s,t)$ is immediate. Note from the definitions that
$$a=s-bc, \\ b= t-ac, \\ c=r-ab. \tag{1}$$
Substitution of two of the right sides of $(1)$ for the corresponding left-side letters of  the product term of each of the three definitions of $r,s,t$ gives the relations
$$r=st-acs-bct+c(abc+1), \\ s=rt-acr-abt+a(abc+1),\\ t=rs-bcr-abs+b(abc+1).\tag{2}$$

Now suppose $d$ divides each of $r,s,t.$ Then from $(2)$ we have that $d$ divides each of 
$a(abc+1)\ ,b(abc+1),\ c(abc+1).$ Now in each of these products the two factors are coprime. For example any prime $p$ dividing both $a$ and $abc+1$ would have to divide $1$, not possible. It follows that, provided we can show that $d$ fails to divide $abc+1$ nontrivially, then we can conclude that $d$ divides each of $a,b,c$, thus that $\gcd(r,s,t)|\gcd(a,b,c)$ to finish the proof.

Now note that, for any independent choices of $\varepsilon_i= \pm 1$, we have that a common divisor  $d$ of $r,s,t$ divides the quantity 
$$\varepsilon_1 c (ab+c)+\varepsilon_2 a(bc+a)+\varepsilon_3 b (ca+b).$$
This last may be rearranged to
$$(\varepsilon_1+\varepsilon_2+\varepsilon_3)(abc+1) + \\
\varepsilon_1 (c^2-1)+\varepsilon_2 (a^2-1)+\varepsilon_3 (b^2-1).$$

Here is where the assumption $\gcd(a^2-1,b^2-1,c^2-1)=1$ plays in. If it happened that $d|(abc+1),$ then by choosing specific values for the $\varepsilon_i=\pm 1$ and adding, we can show that $d$ divides each of $2(a^2-1),\ 2(b^2-1), 2(c^2-1)$, so that by assumption we arrive at $d=2$ or $d=1$. Now if $abc+1$ is even, then each of $a,b,c$ is odd, which implies each of $a^2-1,b^2-1,c^2-1$ is even, against the assumption their gcd is 1. So in fact we cannot have $d=2$, and have shown $d=1$ is implied by $d|abc+1.$ This completes the argument, as detailed above.

Comment: Could you answer some of my questions I've asked in the comments? That would be great. Thanks.

Comment: @mathh Do you have a question about my answer above? If so I could answer it. But the only questions I saw in comments were about another user's answer. I did address that in a comment on that answer, but perhaps the person whose answer that is would be a better choice for more details.

Comment: He obviously ignores my questions, so I need someone else to answer them. You've answered one of them, so I thought you could answer a few more. I can't really see anyone else who could help me. I find it really important to understand all this.

Comment: The gcd of $a,b,c$ is the least positive integer of the form $ax+by+cz.$ So if $\gcd(a,b,c)=d$ and $\gcd(a',b,c)=d'$ we can take $ax+by+cz=d$ and $a'x'+by'+cz'=d'$ and multiply them to get $dd'$ on the right, and (after expanding the left product and grouping) the left side is $aa'u+bv+cw.$ Now since $\gcd(aa',b,c)$ is the least positive integer of this form, we see that $\gcd(aa',b,c) \le \gcd(a,b,c) \cdot \gcd(a',b,c).$ This may be applied repeatedly to get a gcd inequality bounding $\gcd(ap,bq,cr)$ in terms of the eight possible gcd's formed by taking one factor from $a,p$ etc.

Comment: That still doesn't explain $$\gcd(a(c^2-1),c(b^2-1),b(a^2-1))\le \gcd(a,b,c)\gcd(a^2-1,b^2-1,c^2-1)$$

I've proven using your method that $$\gcd(a(a^2-1),a(b^2-1),a(c^2-1),b(a^2-1),b(b^2-1),b(c^2-1),c(a^2-1),c(b^2-1),c(c^2-1))\le \gcd(a,b,c)\gcd(a^2-1,b^2-1,c^2-1)$$

But that doesn't prove that $$\gcd(a(c^2-1),c(b^2-1),b(a^2-1))\le \gcd(a,b,c)\gcd(a^2-1,b^2-1,c^2-1)$$

You've helped me a lot so far but I still can't understand that inequality.

Comment: You've told me that most of them happen to be $1$. How, e.g., is it true that $$\gcd(a,c(b^2-1),b(a^2-1))=1 ?$$
Oh, nevermind. That's since $\gcd(a,a^2-1)=1$. You can ignore my questions. Thanks for all the help, it has really helped me out.

Comment: But wait, how do we know that $$\gcd(a,c(b^2-1),b(a^2-1))=1$$ If we don't know that $\gcd(a\:;b)=1$?

Comment: @mathh You keep going and get four terms from this. The first is gcd(a,c,b), Then there would be gcd(a,b^2-1,b) which is 1. Third is gcd(a,c,a^2-1), again this is 1. The fourth is gcd(a,b^2-1,a^2-1) which is also 1. So you wind up with the gcd of your last comment is at most gcd(a,b,c) since the other three terms in the expansion are 1.

Answer (score 1):

- if $n$ divides $a$, $b$ and $c$ then it divides $(ab+c,bc+a,ca+b)$. Hence
    $$gcd(a,b,c)\le gcd(ab+c,bc+a,ca+b) \quad [1]$$
- if $n$ divides $ab+c$, $bc+a$ and $ca+b$, then it divides
    $$c(ca+b)-(bc+a)=a(c^2-1)$$
    $$b(bc+a)-(ab+c)=c(b^2-1)$$
    $$a(ab+c)-(ca+b)=b(a^2-1)$$

  Hence $$gcd(ab+c,bc+a,ca+b)\le gcd(a(c^2-1),c(b^2-1),b(a^2-1))\quad [2]$$

Now, we know that $$gcd(xy,z)\le gcd(x,z).gcd(y,z)$$

and $gcd(a,a^2-1)=1$ (the same for $b$ and $c$) (So when you develop all terms you can ignore any gcd that contains $x$ and $x^2-1$)

Hence $$gcd(a(c^2-1),c(b^2-1),b(a^2-1))\le gcd(a,b,c).gcd(a^2-1,b^2-1,c^2-1)=gcd(a,b,c)$$

Hence (from $[2]$)  $$gcd(ab+c,bc+a,ca+b)\le gcd(a,b,c) \quad [3]$$

---

Now from $[1]$ and $[3]$,

$$gcd(ab+c,bc+a,ca+b)=gcd(a,b,c)$$

Comment: Sorry for a late comment, didn't have time to go through the answers before. By $gcd(xy,z) \le gcd(x,z).gcd(y,z)$ you meant $\gcd(xy,z) \le \gcd(x,z) \cdot \gcd(y,z)$, right? This is a well-known fact, right? But how to prove it? And it's true that $$\gcd(a_1b_1,a_2b_2,\ldots,a_nb_n) \le \gcd(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n) \cdot \gcd(b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n)$$ right? How to prove this? Thanks. And sorry if I'm bothering you too much.

Comment: @math The last displayed inequality in your previous comment isn't true in general. One has to include a separate factor for each possible choice of one factor from each. For example $\gcd(ab,cd)\le\gcd(a,c)\gcd(a,d)\gcd(b,c)\gcd(b,d)$, and in general with each entry having two factors, and there being $n$ numbers in the gcd, there will initially be $2^n$ factors on the right of the inequality. In Xoff's answer most of these happen to be 1 so they were dropped.

Comment: How can we know that $\gcd(a(c^2-1),c(b^2-1),b(a^2-1))\le \gcd(a,b,c)\gcd(a^2-1,b^2-1,c^2-1)$? I can't see how the fact that $\gcd(ab,cd)\le\gcd(a,c)\gcd(a,d)\gcd(b,c)\gcd(b,d)$ can yield me this.

Comment: It's weird how he showed that $\gcd(xy,z)\le \gcd(x,z)\gcd(y,z)$, but obviously used a different fact or at least a bit different form of it for showing that $\gcd(a(c^2-1),c(b^2-1),b(a^2-1))\le \gcd(a,b,c)\gcd(a^2-1,b^2-1,c^2-1)$. People should thoroughly explain every step they take when they teach other people how to solve a problem.

Comment: I'm sorry for bothering you, but I'll need some help until I fully understand all this. This is very important for me to know.

Comment: And isn't it actually that $\gcd(xy,z)=\gcd(x,z)\gcd(y,z)$ is only true when $\gcd(x,y)=1$?